# Enthought Canopy - passing sys.argv from PySide Qt program

Tags: pyside, enthought, canopy

I've recently been looking at the Enthought distro of iPython.  Today I decided to see if I could get some Qt GUI progs running and was successful after making minor changes.  Simple example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui    # was 'from PyQT4 import QtGui'

# app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)   -- not needed

win = QtGui.QWidget()

win.resize(320, 240)  
win.setWindowTitle("Hello MIT 6X!") 
win.show()

sys.exit()   # was 'sys.exit(app.exec_())'
```

But I would like to be able to pass `sys.argv` in some cases.  Most example code I see is in the form of the commented out `'app = '` line above.  If I include it, I get

> 'RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.'

Suggestions for passing arguments appreciated.

Comment: are you attempting to run a Qt program from *within* an IPython terminal? If so, how can command line arguments have any meaning to your program?

Comment: Yes - thank you.  I was coming to this conclusion after spending much of the last 3 hours looking at documentation, and after reading your comment tried it in the IDLE shell that Enthought also sets up, and it seems to do what I want from there.  I'll just have to remember to use IDLE instead of the Canopy Code Editor while learning Qt.

Comment: You can also just run from a command line: `python my_file.py` That way it doesn't matter what you write your code in (any text editor, IDLE, whatever)

Answer (score 1):

Two separate issues:

1) Passing command line arguments: As you have probably noticed, when you do the "Run" command from the Canopy editor, all it does is issue the IPython %run magic command. You can type the same command in the IPython shell, plus command line parameters, which your program will see. Or to save keystrokes, do this auto-generated Run command once, then press Up Arrow in the IPython shell to recall that auto-generated %run command, then enter your parameters after the filename, and then press Enter. You'll end up with an IPython magic command like this:

```
%run pathtoprog/myprogrampy p1 p2 p3
```

We (Enthought) are considering adding a setting for command-line parameters so that you could do "Run with parameters" and have the best of both worlds.

2) Existing QApplication: By default, Canopy's IPython is running in IPython's interactive Pylab mode, with a Qt backend. If you don't want this, you can just disable Pylab mode in the Canopy Preferences/Python menu, or change the Pylab mode to Inline (for matplotlib) instead of Interactive.

For maximum flexibility, with a bit more work, you could (as matplotlib does) introduce logic which checks whether a QApplication already exists, use it if it exists and create it if it does not.